# In which points is the supremum norm on $C[0,1]$ and $c_0$, respectively, Gâteaux/Fréchet differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

> $f : U \to Y$ where $U\subset X$ is open and $X, Y$ are normed spaces is called Gâteaux differetiable at $u\in U$ if there exists a bounded linear operator $T$ from $U$ to $Y$ such that for $h\to 0$ we have
> $$
> \frac{f(u+hv)-f(u)}{h} \to Tv
> $$
> for all $v\in U$. $f$ is called Fréchet differentiable if the convergence is uniform in $v\in B_X$ (the closed unit ball in $X$).

Here, let $f=\|\|$ be the supremum norm on the space $C[0,1]$ (the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$) and $c_0$ (the space of null convergent sequences), respectively.

Unfortunately, I haven't come very far. It's easy for see that in neither space $\|.\|$ can be differentiable at $0$. Also for both spaces, the triangle inequality yields
$$
\frac{\|f_0+h g\|-\|f_0\|}{h}
\leq \frac{\|f_0\|+\|h g\|-\|f_0\|}{h}
= \|g\|\, .
$$
So the derivative's norm, if it exists, must be bounded by $1$.

Moreover, as the norm is homogeneous, $\lambda f_0$ is differentiable for some $\lambda > 0$, then so is $f_0$.

From here, I don't know how to proceed. One idea I had: Since we have the upper bound for $T$ which has to be a linear functional, it might be possible to invoke something like of the Hahn-Banach theorem. But I don't quite see how to make a connection.

Can anyone help me with this? (And also with the $c_0$ case?)

Comment: Think of $|g|$'s having their maximum at the same point as $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Suppose that $\sup |f(x)|=f(x_0)>0$; then if $\sup|g(x)|=g(x_0)>0$ and $h>0$, we have $\sup|f+hg| = \sup |f| + h\sup |g|$.

Comment: For such $g$ the different quotient would again converge to $\|g\|$ and thus no derivative exists? But what does that give me for the general case?

Comment: No norm can ever be differentiable at the origin. In a _Hilbert space_ the norm is differentiable elsewhere (since it is the square root of a continuous bilinear form). In a general normed space, this can be a tough question and I would not be optimistic in thinking is possible to characterise the set of points where the norm is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lemma by Banach that in $C(K)$ for $K$ compact and metrizable, $\|\cdot \|$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $f\in C(K)$ iff $|f|$ attains a strict maximum.

Reference: Lemma 1.2.1 in **Isometries on Banach Spaces: Function Spaces** by *James E. Jamison* and *Richard J. Fleming*.